# Ordinary kriging problem after exporting to raster (Geostatistical Wizard)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, interpolation, kriging, geostatistical-analyst

I'm not sure what I'm making wrong. I used the Geostatistical Wizard to perform an ordinary kriging. The resulting Geostatistical Layer looks like this:

[image]

After using the `GA Layer To Grid Tool` by right clicking - Data - Export Raster, the resulting raster looks like this:

[image]

I think it's not a problem generated by the `GA Layer to Grid Tool` because if I go to Layer Prop - Symbology in the Layer Properties of the GA Layer, and change to Grid, the resulting grid also shows the breaks.

Can someone tell me, what is happening? Why do you see the regular borders in the second figure? Here you can see my input for the kriging:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think I know at which point the problem arises. I have to choose **"Neighboorhood type - SMOOTH"** in **Geostatistical Wizard - Searching Neighborhood** what is going to use a sigmoidal function defined by the smoothing factor to adjust the weights. After that, I'll not get any breaks by exporting or converting.

[image]

[image]